# How to pay capital gains tax for US non-residents?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Some time ago, I worked in the US, set up a brokerage account and bought some stocks, and soon returned to my home country (Canada). Now I sold some of it, and it occurred to me that I probably need to pay tax on the capital gained. How is this tax normally collected?

If my bank or the IRS tries to send bills to my US address, nobody is monitoring my mail so I won't be able to receive it. They also don't have my address in Canada. Will this potentially cause problems in the future, or can I forget about it and let it take care of itself?

The actual monetary amount is not that big, so I have no problem with paying whatever I owe plus interest, when they ask for it. I just want to make sure it doesn't ruin my credit or cause problems at the border in the future.

Comment: Side note:  has the US brokerage account continued your US "tax presence", necessitating filing US income tax annually on your world-wide income?

Comment: The US Government doesn't bill you for income taxes. They expect you to file a return to pay taxes.

Comment: How did you sell if they don't know your location? Did you use a website, app or phone? If so those will also have an option to update your mailing address, and the first two will usually have options to receive your (monthly or at least quarterly) statements _and_ your year-end tax information (form 1099-B) electronically. (The firms I deal with not only have electronic options but push them at every opportunity -- "get your forms faster and save a tree (and by the way save us money on printing and postage)".)